# C++ | Doesn't execute resource in memory

Tags: c, winapi

help me resolve the issue. I'm trying to load a resource into memory and restore it, but nothing happens

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDR_BIN1 102

int main() {

    HRSRC shellcodeResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_BIN1), "BIN1");
    DWORD shellcodeSize = SizeofResource(NULL, shellcodeResource);
    HGLOBAL shellcodeResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, shellcodeResource);

    void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, shellcodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, shellcodeResourceData, shellcodeSize);
    ((void(*)())exec)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has no check to see if `FindResource`, `SizeofResource` and `LoadResource` are successful.  You should be checking the return code for these functions, and if any fail, call `GetLastError`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: You put C++ in your question title but C in the tags. Which one is it? If you leave it wrong, many people won't even see your question.

Comment: You need to use [LockResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-lockresource) to get a pointer to the actual resource data.

Comment: As with almost anything to do with the Windows API, you need to follow [working sample programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources#updating-resources) to know *exactly* what to do.  You see the `LockResource` being called.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, you need to use `LockResource()` to get a pointer to the actual resource data. `LoadResource()` does not return such a pointer, as you are expecting.

Try this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDR_BIN1 102

int main() {

    HRSRC shellcodeResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_BIN1), "BIN1");
    if (!shellcodeResource) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    HGLOBAL shellcodeResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, shellcodeResource);
    if (!shellcodeResourceData) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    void* shellcodeResourceDataPtr = LockResource(shellcodeResourceData);
    if (!shellcodeResourceDataPtr) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    DWORD shellcodeSize = SizeofResource(NULL, shellcodeResource);

    void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, shellcodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!exec) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    memcpy(exec, shellcodeResourceDataPtr, shellcodeSize);

    ((void(*)())exec)();

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, unless your shell code is self-modifying, you shouldn't be using `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`.  Use `PAGE_READWRITE` when writing the shell code into the memory block, and then change the memory's protection to `PAGE_EXECUTE` before running the shell code, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDR_BIN1 102

int main() {

    HRSRC shellcodeResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_BIN1), "BIN1");
    if (!shellcodeResource) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    HGLOBAL shellcodeResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, shellcodeResource);
    if (!shellcodeResourceData) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    void* shellcodeResourceDataPtr = LockResource(shellcodeResourceData);
    if (!shellcodeResourceDataPtr) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    DWORD shellcodeSize = SizeofResource(NULL, shellcodeResource);

    void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, shellcodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!exec) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    memcpy(exec, shellcodeResourceDataPtr, shellcodeSize);

    DWORD dwOldProtect;
    VirtualProtect(exec, shellcodeSize, PAGE_EXECUTE, &dwOldProtect);

    ((void(*)())exec)();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. If I do “file.bin” directly through a file, then everything is ok, but if through a resource, then not so.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "doesn't work" exactly. What does the shell code look like? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Maybe you didn't setup the resource correctly to begin with? We can't see how you did that. Did you *verify* the resource actually exists in the `.exe` and has the exact same bytes as the `.bin` file?

Comment: Yes, .exe corresponds to .bin

Comment: The resource is added correctly, I can see it through "ResourceHacker", but the resource itself is not executed

Comment: "*is not executed*" is not helpful. What EXACTLY happens? What are you EXPECTING to happen? What is ACTUALLY happening? Are you getting an error? Have you tried using a debugger to verify the app is stepping into the expected shellcode at runtime? DETAILS matter, please.

Comment: Look, the error occurs when I need to execute the shellcode “((void(*)())exec)();”, when I don’t use resources, but take the code directly from the “.bin” file and execute it in memory, then everything is ok

Comment: WHAT ERROR??  You haven't explained the error you are experiencing.  BE SPECIFIC!!!  Provide a [mcve] including the actual shellcode.  For all we know, the shell code is faulty in this context.  How do you expect anyone to help you when you don't EXPLAIN THE PROBLEM clearly enough?